# suspectible-infected-recover(SIR) model in python for influencer detection

Tags: python, networkx, social-networking, sna, propagation

I am searching in identify influencer in social media .but I do not know how can I apply SIR propagation model on special network to evaluate my algorithm to identify influencer in social media. would you send to me python code of SIR model for this ?

Comment: I don't think people will be able to answer your question on this forum - it's too broad.  One place to start would be to look at the [EoN package](https://epidemicsonnetworks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package  that is set up for SIR modeling (disclaimer - I wrote it).  But I don't know much about using it in the context you're thinking of.